# Post and get result with PHP

Tags: php, post, libcurl

From a PHP page, I'm trying to POST some data to another PHP page and get data back.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<?php 
// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init('postpage.php');

// Set some options on the session
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('field1' => 'Andrew'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);

// Close the session
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and in postpage.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Receipt of post request. field1:'.$_POST["field1"];
?>
```

All the var_dump gives me is this:

```
string(0) ""
```

Why am I not getting the text back?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the *actual* `curl_init()` you're using? If so, you'll need to use a fully qualified URL (protocol, hostname, URI).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curl executed from your php script is not aware of the current environment, that is, you cannot use relative urls. The url you supply to curl_init must be absolute (i.e. including http://)

Answer (score 2):

If this is indeed the actual initialization you're doing, the error may lie in the arguments of `curl_init()` which expects a fully qualified URL.

Also, you might want to employ some error diagnostics. `curl_exec` returns `FALSE` on failure. The reason why can be determined with [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php):

```
$ch = curl_init( ... );
// ... some curl_setopt()
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE)
{
    die("cURL error: " . curl_error($ch));
}
```

Comment: +1 for the error diagnostics. In many situations turning `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` on will also help a lot with debugging.